# Make DIV tags even

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I get this DIV to start at the same height i.e when you delete content e.g the paragraph on title 2, the DIV becomes misplaced (start at different heights} thanks

```css
.holder {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 15px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box">
    <h4>title 1</h4>
    <p>
      This is the hidden text that was revealed when the header was clicked. Such hidden text is generally related to the main header which opens them. You can add any number of collapsible headers
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h4>title 2</h4>
    <p>
      This is the hidden text that was revealed when the header was clicked. Such hidden text is generally related to the main header which opens them. You can add any number of collapsible headers
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-height` and `vertical-align: top` ; will help you.

The main reason why `vertical-align: top` works is because it is applied to an inline block element. If the display on `.box` was just `block` it wouldn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>height</title>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   
  })
 </script>
 <style>
  .holder {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
   min-height: 400px;
    margin: 15px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="holder">
   <div class="box">
     <h4>title 1</h4>
     <p>
       This is the hidden text that was revealed when the header was clicked. Such hidden text is generally related to the main header which opens them. You can add any number of collapsible headers
     </p>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
     <h4>title 2</h4>
     <p>
      
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I also wanted to let know that the height is usually referred to the  dimension of an element (400px). I think  when you referred to height you meant the top position of the element (location) relative the document. I think that is what you were trying to achieve .  Also you can set `min-height` to set the min height of the element and `max-height` to make it so that the container cant be larger height wise than  a specific amount. just an FYI